# Configure Hydra-7.4.2 on Windows 7 using Cygwin

Tags: compilation, cygwin, hydra

I am trying to configure THC Hydra 7.4.2 on my Windows 7 laptop with Cygwin. I installed Cygwin using setup.exe, I have selected devel and MinGW pakages.

When I execute ./configure it is fine.. although some missing modules were mentioned. Then I was prompted 'now type "make"'.

When I do this I get the following error message:

```
PC@Z-PC ~/hydra/hydra-7.4.2
$ ./configure

Starting hydra auto configuration ...

Checking for openssl (libssl, libcrypto, ssl.h, sha.h) ...
                                                       ... found
Checking for idn (libidn.so) ...
                             ... found
Checking for curses (libcurses.so / term.h) ...
                                            ... found, color output enabled
Checking for pcre (libpcre.so, pcre.h) ...
                                       ... found
Checking for Postgres (libpq.so, libpq-fe.h) ...
                                             ... found
Checking for SVN (libsvn_client-1 libapr-1.so libaprutil-1.so) ...
                                                               ... found
Checking for firebird (libfbclient.so) ...
                                       ... NOT found, module firebird disabled
Checking for MYSQL client (libmysqlclient.so, math.h) ...
                                                      ... NOT found, module Mysq               l will not support version > 4.x
Checking for AFP (libafpclient.so) ...
                                   ... NOT found, module Apple Filing Protocol d               isabled - Apple sucks anyway
Checking for NCP (libncp.so / nwcalls.h) ...
                                         ... NOT found, module NCP disabled
Checking for SAP/R3 (librfc/saprfc.h) ...
                                      ... NOT found, module sapr3 disabled
Get it from http://www.sap.com/solutions/netweaver/linux/eval/index.asp
Checking for libssh (libssh/libssh.h) ...
                                      ... NOT found, module ssh disabled
Get it from http://www.libssh.org
Checking for Oracle (libocci.so libclntsh.so / oci.h and libaio.so) ...
                                                                    ... NOT foun               d, module Oracle disabled
Get basic and sdk package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/featur               es/instant-client/index.html
Checking for GUI req's (pkg-config, gtk+-2.0) ...
                                              ... found

Hydra will be installed into .../bin of: /usr/local
  (change this by running ./configure --prefix=path)

Writing Makefile.in ...

Cygwin detected, if compilation fails just update your installation.

Windres found, will attach icons to hydra cygwin executables

now type "make"

PC@Z-PC ~/hydra/hydra-7.4.2
$ make
gcc -I. -O3 -lm    -o hydra hydra-logo.o hydra.c hydra-vnc.o hydra-pcnfs.o hydra               -rexec.o hydra-nntp.o hydra-socks5.o  hydra-telnet.o hydra-cisco.o hydra-http.o                hydra-ftp.o hydra-imap.o  hydra-pop3.o hydra-smb.o hydra-icq.o hydra-cisco-enabl               e.o hydra-ldap.o  hydra-mysql.o hydra-mssql.o hydra-xmpp.o hydra-http-proxy-urle               num.o  hydra-snmp.o hydra-cvs.o hydra-smtp.o hydra-smtp-enum.o hydra-sapr3.o hyd               ra-ssh.o  hydra-sshkey.o hydra-teamspeak.o hydra-postgres.o hydra-rsh.o hydra-rl               ogin.o  hydra-oracle-listener.o hydra-svn.o hydra-pcanywhere.o hydra-sip.o  hydr               a-oracle-sid.o hydra-oracle.o hydra-vmauthd.o hydra-firebird.o hydra-afp.o hydra               -ncp.o  hydra-http-proxy.o hydra-http-form.o hydra-irc.o  hydra-rdp.o crc32.o d3               des.o bfg.o ntlm.o sasl.o hmacmd5.o hydra-mod.o -lm -lcurses -lssl -lidn -lpcre                -lpq -lsvn_client-1 -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lcrypto -L/usr/lib -L/usr/               local/lib -L/lib -L/lib -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/               include/subversion-1 -DLIBOPENSSL -DLIBOPENSSLNEW -DLIBNCURSES -DLIBIDN -DHAVE_P               R29_H -DHAVE_PCRE -DLIBPOSTGRES -DLIBSVN -DHAVE_MATH_H
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-connect.o): In function `ldapServiceLookup':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3541: undefined reference to `_ldap_init'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3553: undefined reference to `_ldap_simple_bind'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3563: undefined reference to `_ldap_result'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3576: undefined reference to `_ldap_msgfree'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3580: undefined reference to `_ldap_search_st'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3584: undefined reference to `_ldap_msgfree'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3585: undefined reference to `_ldap_err2string'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3588: undefined reference to `_ldap_unbind'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3594: undefined reference to `_ldap_count_entries'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3622: undefined reference to `_ldap_msgfree'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3623: undefined reference to `_ldap_unbind'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3569: undefined reference to `_ldap_msgfree'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3573: undefined reference to `_ldap_unbind'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3606: undefined reference to `_ldap_first_entry'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3618: undefined reference to `_ldap_get_values_len'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3628: undefined reference to `_ldap_msgfree'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3648: undefined reference to `_ldap_value_free_len'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3649: undefined reference to `_ldap_unbind'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3661: undefined reference to `_ldap_value_free_len'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-connect.c:3662: undefined reference to `_ldap_unbind'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-misc.o): In function `libpq_gettext':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-misc.c:1202: undefined reference to `_libintl_bindtextdomain'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-misc.c:1210: undefined reference to `_libintl_dgettext'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-misc.o): In function `pqSocketCheck':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-misc.c:1025: undefined reference to `_SSL_pending'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `initialize_SSL':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1094: undefined reference to `_SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file               '
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1104: undefined reference to `_SSL_use_certificate_file'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1183: undefined reference to `_SSL_use_PrivateKey'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1253: undefined reference to `_SSL_check_private_key'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1281: undefined reference to `_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1292: undefined reference to `_SSL_CTX_get_cert_store'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1322: undefined reference to `_SSL_set_verify'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1239: undefined reference to `_SSL_use_PrivateKey_file'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1357: undefined reference to `_SSL_ctrl'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `init_ssl_system':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:946: undefined reference to `_TLSv1_method'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `pqsecure_write':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:491: undefined reference to `_SSL_get_error'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `pqsecure_read':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:330: undefined reference to `_SSL_get_error'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `close_SSL':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1466: undefined reference to `_SSL_shutdown'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1467: undefined reference to `_SSL_free'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `open_client_SSL':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1432: undefined reference to `_SSL_get_peer_certificate'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:1381: undefined reference to `_SSL_get_error'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(fe-secure.o): In function `pqsecure_open_client':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/src/postgresql-9.2.4/src/interfaces/lib               pq/fe-secure.c:259: undefined reference to `_SSL_set_ex_data'
/usr/lib/libpq.a(chklocale.o): In function `pg_get_encoding_from_locale':
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/build/src/interfaces/libpq/chklocale.c:               269: undefined reference to `_libintl_setlocale'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/build/src/interfaces/libpq/chklocale.c:               277: undefined reference to `_libintl_setlocale'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/build/src/interfaces/libpq/chklocale.c:               292: undefined reference to `_libintl_setlocale'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/build/src/interfaces/libpq/chklocale.c:               298: undefined reference to `_libintl_setlocale'
/pub/devel/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.4-1/build/src/interfaces/libpq/chklocale.c:               351: undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:51: recipe for target `hydra' failed
make: *** [hydra] Error 1
```

I am not sure whats wrong with it.. I tried reinstalling Cygwin with all packages (after huge download time) and also with default packages but none of it works.. any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems there aren't anyone with relevant experience on this site. I am bit disappointed with how this site work.. If I ask simple question then people will jump for negative votes and if I ask something serious then I would not even receive single comment.

Anyways, I am still not sure what is wrong with "Hydra-7.4.2", note that I have installed complete cygwin package and still getting "make" error while compiling hydra.

For sake of testing I installed and compiled "Hydra-6.1"... and luckily it worked! 
Hence if anyone is getting same error then try moving to previous version, or if u crack this out then please share the details.

Comment: I guess it caused by missing packages or wrong installation (32bit on 64bit system) - which was the problem in my similar case: Hydra 7.5 + Cygwin latest with "default" packages setup.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Hydra 7.6 on Cygwin. It disables the usage of PostgreSQL, configure says:

```
Checking for Postgres (libpq.so, libpq-fe.h) ...
                                         ... DISABLED - postgres is buggy in Cygwin at the moment
```

I guess there's the answer to your problem. It's buggy.